# Need information about spring Controllers

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am very confused about spring controllers,
pls help me.

i want to know that how spring controller initate and how its constructor get into action,

as when i call a controller  from one page, and then ask the same controller from another page it dosn't seems to create a new object of that controller rather than provide same reference of the controller object

Comment: I believe that the spring documentation is quite verbose. You should start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers are "application-scoped"; they are instantiated just once and then reused for all requests you associate them with. As such, it is important that they do not carry session-specific state.

You should refer to [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) for more details on how controllers work and how to instantiate them.